# Is it possible to populate a reference to a sub-document array objectid on another model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

**SampleModel**:

```
{
    "Name": String,
    "brandid": {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'BrandList.BrandItems',
    }
}
```

**BrandModel**:

```
{
    "BrandName" : String,
    "BrandItems": [{
        "KG": Number,
        "_id" : {type: Schema.ObjectId}
    }]
}
```

How do I reference subdocument array's `ObjectId` to another model and also how do I use `populate()` for this "brandid"?

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb does not have foreign keys. Your will have to do it in application code.